# How do I edit the columns on a Lookup pop-up window?

Tags: community, lookup

Is it possible to edit the values in the Lookup popup window? If this cannot be done in classic can it be done in Lightning?

Answer (score 0):

The columns can be configured in the object's Search Layouts (for the Lookup Dialogs):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_searchlayout.htm

Comment: ok but can you be on the popup window and edit it? If not can you create a javascript function to do it or is that impossible?

Comment: The standard platform functionality only allows the columns shown in the lookup search to be set once per object in the search layout. You could write something custom to achieve to allow users to edit the columns, but I don't think the effort would be worth the value unless there is a critical need for it